# boto3 list only objects of a specific storage class in s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

This is an efficiency problem. I am using `boto3` to selectively download files from an S3 bucket. The problem is that I have about 50k records in a folder and over 70% of them are in **GLACIER**/**DEEP_ARCHIVE**. I am using `list_objects_v2` to iterate the files.

In Java, I can pass a flag to filter out GLACIER/DEEP_ARCHIVE objects in the API call. It does not seem to be supported in Python's boto3 SDK, as far as I have looked. If you have come across a similar problem, how did you tackle it?

Here is my code:

```
def download_log_files(
    logger: logging.Logger,
    log_file_codes: list[int],
    aws_s3_credentials: Dict[str, str],
    local_download_dir: str,
):
    """Download all log files from S3 bucket to disk.

    Args:
        logger (logging.Logger): For logging.
        log_file_codes (list[int]): The log file codes.
        aws_s3_credentials (Dict[str, str]): The AWS S3 credentials.
        local_download_dir (str): The local directory to download the log files to.
    """
    for log_file_code in log_file_codes:
        logger.debug(f"Downloading log files for log: {log_file_code}")
        s3_folder_name = str(log_file_code).zfill(4)
        s3 = boto3.client(
            "s3",
            aws_access_key_id=aws_s3_credentials["s3_user_id"],
            aws_secret_access_key=aws_s3_credentials["s3_user_secret"],
        )

        paginator = s3.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")
        pages = paginator.paginate(
            Bucket=aws_s3_credentials["s3_logs_bucket_name"],
            Prefix=s3_folder_name,
            # TODO: pass attribute to filter by StorageClass
        )
        if pages is None:
            logger.error(
                f"Could not retrieve bucket contents for {s3_folder_name}. Skipping log: {log_file_code}"
            )
            continue

        local_download_folder = Path(f"{local_download_dir}/{s3_folder_name}")
        if not os.path.exists(local_download_folder):
            os.makedirs(local_download_folder)

        # Download and extract all log files from S3 bucket
        for page in pages:
            for obj in page["Contents"]:
                # If it is in GLACIER or DEEP_ARCHIVE, then skip it.
                # This can be sped up if this filter is part of the API call
                if (
                    obj["StorageClass"] == "GLACIER"
                    or obj["StorageClass"] == "DEEP_ARCHIVE"
                ):
                    continue
                
                # Download the file ...
                pass
```

Comment: As per the [list_objects_v2 - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/list_objects_v2.html), it is not possible to pass a filter (aside from `Prefix`). You will need to filter the results in your Python code. An alternative approach is to use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects. It will include the storage class of each object.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yikes - i was hoping there was something one could pass in the `OptionalObjectAttributes` param, like 'RestoreStatus'. oh well - i will take a look at the Inventory angle. cheers

Comment: Oh, I've never actually noticed that `OptionalObjectAttributes` field. It looks like it just impacts that fields that are returned, but isn't a way of filtering which objects are returned.